# user can submit data with photo.But here i can't check the image content.how to check here with mime

Tags: php, postgresql, mime-types

```
    <?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))  
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} 
else 
    {
    $imagepath = "propertyimages/".(rand()) . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $imagepath);

    $db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=ohms user=postgres password=padmin");
     $s="select dcode from dept where dname='$_POST[select]'";   
      $s1=pg_query($s);  
    $row=pg_fetch_array($s1);
     $row[0]; 
    $r = pg_fetch_row($s1);
    $query = "INSERT INTO nsr VALUES ('$_POST[text1]','$_POST[text2]',  
    '$_POST[textarea]','$row[0]','$_POST[textfield3]', '$_POST[text5]','$_POST[text6]','$_POST[text7]','$_POST[text8]','$_POST[textfield]','$_POST[text10]','$_POST[ref_phno]','$d','".$imagepath."')";  
    $result = pg_query($query);
}}
```

**tish is the code of a registration  page.user cane submit data with image.here user can submit various image extension .but want insert thost image whose content are image..not a txt with .jpg extension how to do this.please help**

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). and generally speaking, you do **NOT** want to save the raw binary image data in your db. there's very few usage cases that justify it, and many that make it a major pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getimagesize` function in PHP. If the file is a valid image, the first two parameters will be the width/height. You can check if those numbers are acceptable (e.g. this will accept width/height to be between 128-2048 pixels).

After `move_uploaded_file`, insert this code:

```
$arr = getimagesize( $imagepath );
if( $arr[0] >= 128 && $arr[1] >= 128 && $arr[0] <= 2048 && $arr[1] <= 2048 )
{
  // valid image
}
else
{
  // error
}
```

Note: you should use the built-in `pathinfo` function to get the extension: `pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION )`.